# Using rqt_plot functionality with dictionary element in parameter

Tags: ros-kinetic, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to use `rqt_plot` functionality that involves dictionary but couldn't get it displayed. Obviously, something is not correct somewhere.

```
rostopic echo /gazebo/model_states
```

gives me something like below:

```
name: ['ground_plane', 'asphalt_plane', 'first_2015_trash_can']
pose: 
- 
position: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
orientation: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
  w: 1.0
- 
position: 
  x: 0.775434
  y: 2.97518
  z: 0.0
orientation: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
  w: 1.0
  - 
position: 
  x: 3.82387818665
  y: 3.40090985756
  z: 0.0500026991437
orientation: 
  x: 5.04793066057e-05
  y: -1.94916170948e-05
  z: -0.00420963773061
  w: 0.999991137972
```

What I'm interested in is the x-position of `first_2015_trash_can` i.e. one of the pose information of  the third object. I've tried to do

```
rqt_plot /gazebo/model_states/name:'first_2015_trash_can'/pose/position/x
```

but didn't succeed. I've also tried:

```
rqt_plot  /gazebo/model_states/name[2]:pose/position/x
```

but doesn't work either.

Any ideas what could go wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274818/using-rqt_plot-functionality-with-dictionary-element-in-parameter/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2017-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You were close but try something along the lines of

```
rqt_plot /gazebo/model_states/pose[2]/position/x
```

As far as I can tell, the `name` parameter tells you what position in the `pose` array to find the object that you want to examine so there's no need to use it with plotting. So, with my example we'd be looking at the x position of the `first_2015_trash_can` object. Also, note how I'm *not* using the `:`.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2017-11-07**:
@jayess: Thanks a lot for the answer and explanation. But it still not working as the values for all elements give zero values. I guess there is a bug in the current rqt_plot. I have just upgraded the rqt_plot last week.